# Speed up for loop in Matlab

Tags: performance, matlab, for-loop, vectorization

I have the following `for` loop which makes my program runs very slow when the file size is very big. What is the best way to vectorize it.

I read `data` from a PLY file as [here](http://wikisend.com/download/891702/testPly.ply) using the command, `data = textread(fileName, '%s','delimiter', '\n');`.`data` is a n*1 cell array. Each element in `data` is a 7*1 cell array of char values. Sample data file is [here](http://wikisend.com/download/893286/data.mat).

```
for i = 1:length(data)-1
    pc(i, 1) = (str2double(cellstr(data{i,1}{1,1})));
    pc(i, 2) = (str2double(cellstr(data{i,1}{2,1})));
    pc(i, 3) = (str2double(cellstr(data{i,1}{3,1})));
    pc(i, 4) = (str2double(cellstr(data{i,1}{4,1})));
    pc(i, 5) = (str2double(cellstr(data{i,1}{5,1})));
    pc(i, 6) = (str2double(cellstr(data{i,1}{6,1})));
end
```

Comment: Please post a [mcve].

Comment: what is the content of `data` ?

Comment: Just edited the post explaining data. data variable is created from the data read from a file.

Comment: @Hwathanie Paste an example of data into the question that we can work with. Not a picture!

Comment: If you read your data into this format, you are probably better off changing the way you load your files; e.g. loading directly into a matrix, since they are numbers anyway

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will do what you want

```
>> pc = str2double([data{:}].')
pc =
    0.1033   -0.2737    0.8570  221.0000  196.0000  174.0000  255.0000
    0.1054   -0.2731    0.8550  220.0000  195.0000  173.0000  255.0000
    ...
    0.1139   -0.2803    0.8490  221.0000  194.0000  172.0000  255.0000
    0.1117   -0.2829    0.8500  225.0000  200.0000  178.0000  255.0000
```

You can remove the last column and row (as appears to be done in your question) with

```
>> pc = pc(1:end-1, 1:end-1)
pc =
    0.1033   -0.2737    0.8570  221.0000  196.0000  174.0000
    0.1054   -0.2731    0.8550  220.0000  195.0000  173.0000
    ...
    0.1139   -0.2803    0.8490  221.0000  194.0000  172.0000
```

Comment: Yes, it perfectly works. Thank you very much. Specially it gave a very good performance improvement from 112.821007 seconds to 21.771251 seconds for a data matrix of size 200,932*1.

Comment: Will there a good way to improve the reading PLY file as well. Currently I use the code, 
data = textread(fileName, '%s','delimiter', '\n');
data = data(15:length(data),1);
data = (cellfun(@(x) strread(x,'%s','delimiter',' '), data, 'UniformOutput', false));
I just commented here since it is relevant, else I can create a new question. Pls suggest. Thank you.

Comment: @Hwathanie That should be a new question. Make sure it has a [mcve] and is answerable and we'll see what we can do.

Comment: Just added the new question (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33451349/speed-up-ply-file-reading-in-matlab). Thank you.