# Speed up PLY file reading

Tags: performance, matlab, matrix, text

Currently I use the following code segment in MATLAB to read a PLY into a MATLAB matrix. [Here is a sample PLY file](http://wikisend.com/download/891702/testPly.ply). But it take a considerable time when the size of the PLY file is quite large.

Is there a better way to read a text file efficiently in MATLAB?

```
data = textread(fileName, '%s','delimiter', '\n');
data = data(15:length(data),1);
data = (cellfun(@(x) strread(x,'%s','delimiter',' '), data, 'UniformOutput', false));
```

(This question is a part of my previous question listed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33445935/speed-up-for-loop-in-matlab/33446208?noredirect=1#comment54689342_33446208).)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`dlmread`](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/dlmread.html) function and make use of its ability to specify a starting position

```
>> data = dlmread(filename, ' ', 14, 0)
data =

    0.1054   -0.2731    0.8550  220.0000  195.0000  173.0000  255.0000         0
    0.1008   -0.2754    0.8550  228.0000  202.0000  184.0000  255.0000         0
    ...
    0.1139   -0.2803    0.8490  221.0000  194.0000  172.0000  255.0000         0
    0.1117   -0.2829    0.8500  225.0000  200.0000  178.0000  255.0000         0
```

The last two arguments specify the starting row and column of the data. The final zeros arise because each of the lines in your test file ends with a space. We can remove these with

```
>> data = data(:, 1:end-1);
```

The [`dlmread`](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/dlmread.html) function reads in numeric data and removes the need for the conversion from a `string` to a `double` in my [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33446208/1552737).

Comment: This is great. Again it improves the time taken very significantly for the given sample file from 0.297907 seconds to 0.044519 seconds. I think my next comment seems should be another new question again. What if I want to read the PLY file from a specific row which contains the text 'end_header'. Pls comment, then I can create a new question.

Comment: Its unclear what you want, do you want to read the text `end_header` as well as the numeric data or do you want to find `end_header` and then read the lines after that? Probably best as a new question.

Comment: Yes, I want to start reading from the line after the string 'end_header'. OK I will initiate a new question.

Comment: Just initiated a new question (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33451725/reading-a-ply-file-from-a-specific-string).