# Reading a PLY file from a specific string

Tags: string, performance, matlab, delimiter, filereader

I want to read a PLY file to a MATLAB matrix starting from the next line of the string end_header using the `dlmread` function as suggested in this [SOF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33451349/speed-up-ply-file-reading/33451467?noredirect=1#comment54689986_33451467) question. Sample PLY file is given [here](http://wikisend.com/download/891702/testPly.ply). Currently the starting line is hardcoded as follows, but it is not suitable as the number of header rows in a PLY file may change.

```
data = dlmread(fileName, ' ', 14, 0);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a multitude off different ways you could do this. One option is to use [`textscan`](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/textscan.html) to read in the entire file and a mix of [`strfind`](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/strfind.html) and [`find`](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/find.html) to determine the row that contains `'end_header'` like

```
filename = 'testPly.ply';

fid = fopen(filename);
data = textscan(fid, '%s', 'delimiter', '\n');
idx = find(cellfun(@isempty, strfind(data{1}, 'end_header')) == 0);
fclose(fid);
```

then you can use [`dlmread`](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/dlmread.html) as

```
data = dlmread(filename, ' ', idx, 0);
```

or extract the numeric data based on my [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33446208/1552737).

---

Another method, which may be better if your files contain a lot of data after `'end_header'` but not a lot before it would be to read each line until you find `'end_header'` using [`fgets`](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fgets.html)

```
idx = 1;
fid = fopen(filename, 'r');
while isempty(strfind(fgets(fid), 'end_header'))
    idx = idx + 1;
end
fclose(fid);
```

and then use [`dlmread`](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/dlmread.html) or extract the numeric data based on my [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33446208/1552737).